# syscalls with PTRACE_ATTACH

Tags: c

i have a simple question about ptrace please. Here is a very simple source code in C:

```
ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, 0, 0);
int status;
waitpid(pid, &status, WSTOPPED);
while (1) {
    ptrace(PTRACE_SINGLESTEP, pid, 0, 0);
    "here i must display a message when a syscall is executed."
}
```

I just want to know what i must add in the loop to write a message (for example "ok") when the process associated with the pid in parameter uses a syscall, without using PTRACE_SYSCALL...Does anybody have an idea?
For example i could get the return value of a call with ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER...) and if this value is not equal to -1...
**I just want to get the return value of each syscall in the process pid without using ptrace_sycall and using ptrace_attach.**
I give you thanks.

Comment: One obvious method, without using any special syscall tracing functionality as you rejected in your edit, would be to continually read the next instruction to be executed and recognize whenever that is one that implements an entry into the kernel as used on your particular platform.  Then after you let this execute you can read the result value as defined in your ABI.

Comment: thanks Chris but i don't know to implement it, look at this webpage there is an example just at the beginning http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/6210/print, i want to do the same thing but with a loop to get all values of the syscalls, do you understand what i mean? thanks.

Comment: First make your program print out the opcode to be executed next.  Then look up the syscall entry mechanism(s) on your unspecified platform.  Now add logic to detect them and set a wasSyscall boolean state variable.  Next interation, if that is set, print the value of whatever storage holds the syscall result in your unspecified ABI.

Comment: You may want to make a simple test program that just does one or two syscalls and single step it under gdb watching the opcodes, and also under the print every opcode version of your program.

Comment: You will need to access memory at the instruction pointer, and likely registers as well after the syscall. The opcode used for a syscall on Linux varies depending on the processor and operating mode.  You are going to have to make more of an effort yourself if you hope to solve this - there's little point in avoiding the mechansim intended for this purpose in order to do it the hard way "as an exercise" if you are unwilling to research the details of the steps once they have been outlined.